# tar --exclude flag not excluding the directory if I add the trailing slash '/' at the end of the path

Tags: tar

If I use this command:

```
sudo tar -zcvpf exclusion.tar.gz mybkup/ --exclude=mybkup/etc/ssh/
```

then If I try to see if the ssh directory is included in the tarball contents I see that in fact is included:

```
[user@smashingx1 ~]$ tar -tvzf exclusion.tar.gz | grep ssh
lrwxrwxrwx user/user         0 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
-rw-r----- user/user       506 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/sysconfig/sshd
-rw-r--r-- user/user      5996 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/
-rw-r--r-- user/user    242153 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/moduli
-rw-r--r-- user/user      2208 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_config
-rw-r--r-- user/user       382 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- user/user       162 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r-- user/user      4760 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/sshd_config
-rw-r--r-- user/user        82 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r----- user/user      1675 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r----- user/user       227 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw------- user/user      4361 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew
-rw-r----- user/user       387 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- user/user      8730 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/rssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user     18774 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/ssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user       904 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

but if I don't add the last '/' at the end of the directory path, then it excludes the directory:

```
sudo tar -zcvpf exclusion.tar.gz mybkup/ --exclude=mybkup/etc/ssh

tar -tvzf exclusion.tar.gz | grep ssh

lrwxrwxrwx user/user         0 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
-rw-r----- user/user       506 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/sysconfig/sshd
-rw-r--r-- user/user      5996 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
-rw-r--r-- user/user      8730 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/rssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user     18774 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/ssh.pp
-rw-r--r-- user/user       904 2016-11-30 04:26 mybkup/etc/pam.d/sshd
```

I am confused because I thought that by instructing tar to exclude the directory, it would exclude the directory and its contents, but apparently is not the case, can somebody explain please?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much you consider it an explanation, but *exclude* options to tar takes the name of the thing to exclude.  In this case you want to exclude a directory called *ssh*.  There isn't anything actually called *ssh/*.  The exclude pattern you give will not match anything.